# Checking if operator is isometrics

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let's consider the operator

$$F: C([0,1]) \rightarrow l^\infty$$
$$F(g) = (g(q_n))$$
where $\{q_n\} = \Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$

I want to check whether this operator is well defined, bounded and if it's an isometry.

Bound of this operator is straightforward:

$$|F(q_n)| = |g(q_n)| \le \|g\|$$

What about isometrics (i.e. $\|g\|_\infty = \|T(g)\|_\infty$) ?

$$\|g\|_\infty = \sup\{|g(x)| , x \in [0,1]\}$$

$$\|T(g)\|=\|g(q_n)\| = \sup\{|g(x)|, x \in \Bbb Q \cap [0,1]\}$$

And, in my opinio,n those two expressions are equal, since $g$ is a continuous function and $\Bbb Q$ is dense, so this supremum, even if it's not reached on rational number, it's not a problem.

Am I thinking correctly ? Is this justification sufficient ?

Comment: Please rewrite the first paragraph so it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $\|F(g)\|=\sup_{n\geq 1}|g(q_{n})|$.

We know that $\|g\|_{\infty}=\max_{[0,1]}|g|=|g(x_{0})|$. Now pick a sequence $(r_{n})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ such that $|g(r_{n})|\rightarrow|g(x_{0})|$, then $|g(x_{0})|=\lim_{n}|g(r_{n})|\leq\sup_{n\geq 1}|g(q_{n})|$.